# All forked processs from linux kernel

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel

How can i list a tree of all forked process from linux kernel module.I know for getting one level of forked process i can use

```
list_for_each_entry(child, &parent->children, sibling) {

}
```

But how can i get all  level ,like

```
Parent
   |
   child 
      | 
       childs_child
```

Like this ,I know recursive function is not good option is in kernel .So how will i traverse 
 through all forked process from parent

Comment: It is a recursive structure, it cannot be traversed without keeping context somewhere. In any case you'll have to allocate memory: either on stack (by recursive calls) or in an allocated kernel memory block (which you'll have to manage).

Comment: You might want to take a look at the code which prints the stack dump when SysRq+t is pressed: it has to go through all processes. It might not do it in the order you want, though.

Comment: @fork0 : Could you please give me a pointer to this code ?